# How can I handle a 401 Unauthorized response differently from other errors in an Angular 8 service using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a REST API that requires a user to be identified by an access token with each call.

Each API endpoint returns a 401 UNAUTHORIZED response if the token is not provided or has expired.

In some cases, I am calling the APIs with a timer.

In my service class:

```
getFoo(id: String): Observable<Foo> {
  return this.http.get<Foo>(url, HTTP_OPTIONS);
}

getFooList(): Observable<Foo[]> {
  return timer(0, FIVE_MINUTES).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.http.get<Foo[]>(url, HTTP_OPTIONS))
  );
}
```

and, then in my component

```
fooList: Foo[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadFooList();
}

private loadFooList() {
  this._fooService.getFooList().subscribe(
    (fooList) =>  this.fooList = fooList,
    (err) => console.error(err)
  );
}
```

How can I put a check *in the service itself* whether I have received a 401 response or not? Rather than having to do this in each component that uses the service?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make an interceptor handle this?

Comment: Yes. There’s a very good reason. I didn’t know such a thing existed (I’m new to angular development), so didn’t know what to look for! I’ll look into interceptors. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an interceptor.

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) { }

  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            if (error.status == 401) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        })
    );
  }
}
```

Added it as a provider in my **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{
     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
     useClass: AuthInterceptor,
     multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,]
})
export class AppModule { }
```